# Can't install unity webapps preview

Tags: 12.04, unity, webapps

I'm trying to install unity-webapps-preview, so I previously added the PPA :

```
    $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
    $ sudo apt-get update
```

but I get the following error :

```
    $ sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies.
    unity-webapps-preview : Depends: xul-ext-unity but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: xul-ext-websites-integration but it is not going to > be installed
                            Depends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to manually install the dependencies and I get :

```
    $ sudo apt-get install xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration xul-ext-webaccounts
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies.
    xul-ext-webaccounts : Breaks: firefox (>= 14.+) but 15.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Version of Firefox : 15.0.1

Version of Ubuntu : 12.04

Comment: Hi,it appears many people are having similar issues with this PPA.Also take note,many broke there machines from un installing,  it apparently removed huge chunks from unity.Its probably a good thing it didn't install and best kept away from for now.

Comment: Removing Firefox doesn't work though, as 14 is a dependency. Probably best to wait for a more official release version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install it because the current unity-webapps-preview package depends on Firefox 14 for some reason (even though it works just fine with 15 and newer) so you'll have to wait for an update to be able to install it.

Comment: Same issue here. This answer is send from Chromium that is installed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Piotrek Sobieszczański in another forum said: "Just remove preview from the end of the package name..`$ sudo apt-get install unity-webapps`". This worked for me.

Comment: Yes, this works in Ubuntu 12.04, thank you.